# Log all flask connections to a log file

Tags: python, logging, flask, ip

I have recently setup a python flask server that will host an at home streaming camera, sort of like a security camera. I was wondering if it is possible, using python and flask, to log all connections that are made to the server. This would include the date, time, and IP that connected.
If I run the flask app in a python IDLE, flask outputs this::

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2018 19:17:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2018 19:17:09] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2018 19:17:13] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2018 19:17:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2018 19:17:13] "GET /fake.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I was wondering if it is possible to log all of this information into a log file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These messages are requests made to the server, so I'm pretty sure the [Requests](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data) module from Flask is what you're looking for.

Just save the Request object (or the attribute you want) at the beginning of each function which is a Flask route (`@app.route("XXX")`)

I made a little test with a Flask app I have and this is what I got:

**Code**

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/')
def main():
    print("HEHEHE: {}".format(request.headers))

@app.route('/getCharacters', methods=['GET'])
def getCharacters():
    print("HIHIHII: {}".format(request.headers))
```

**Result**

```
HEHEHE: Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0


127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 08:59:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 08:59:23] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 08:59:23] "GET /static/chart.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 08:59:23] "GET /static/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 08:59:23] "GET /static/assets/movies/lotr_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 08:59:23] "GET /static/assets/movies/sw_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
HIHIHII: Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:8000/
Connection: keep-alive


127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 09:00:49] "GET /getCharacters?movie=sw HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 09:00:49] "GET /static/assets/pjs/sw/han.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 09:00:49] "GET /static/assets/pjs/sw/vader.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 09:00:49] "GET /static/assets/pjs/sw/threepio.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 09:00:49] "GET /static/assets/pjs/sw/luke.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2018 09:00:49] "GET /static/assets/pjs/sw/leia.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```